# Конфликтуют label4.Text = label4.Text.Remove(0); и label4.Text += $"{n.ToString()}, ";

Tags: c#, winforms

При нажатии на кнопку выдаёт числа в label, кратные какому-то числу (задаётся).
Если нужно второй раз вывести эти числа, нужно, чтобы сначала label очистился (т.к. в выводе стоит +=), а только потом выводил новое решение с другими числами.
По отдельности
`label4.Text = label4.Text.Remove(0);`
и
`label4.Text += $"{n.ToString()}, ";` 
работают.
А вместе не хотят. Что я делаю не так?

```
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            int m = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
for (n = n; n <= m; n++)
        {
            int x = n % a;
            if (x == 0)
               {
                  label4.Text = label4.Text.Remove(0);
                  await Task.Delay(100);
                  label4.Text += $"{n.ToString()}, "; 
               }
```

Comment: Так не делайте `label4.Text +=`, запишите результат в отдельную переменную, которую объявляете в начале метода, а уже потом `label4.Text = result;`. У вас тут каша какая-то, дайте хоть пару замечаний сделаю: 1. Научитесь давать понятные названия переменным, чтоб другие понимали что этот код делает просто, прочитав названия, а то зоопарк целый `n, m, a, x`, жуть! 2. Не используйте `Convert`, он уже по сути давно изжил себя, есть куда лаконичней и приятней решения (`int.Parse()` или `int.TryParse()`). 3. Если в `TextBox` не число, то программа упадет. 4. `$"{n.ToString()}` - `ToString` лишнее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - без `ToString` будет boxing.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov И к чему это тут?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - К тому, что `ToString` в данном конкретном случае не совсем лишний. Он устраняет боксинг, что повышает производительность. Многие анализаторы кода посоветуют его добавить. Но это так, просто примечание.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, только в контексте данной задачи, где человек просто учиться программированию, где он просто по кнопке выводит результат, тут извините, этот `boxing` для него будет как минимум лишней информацией и экономией на спичках. Так что лично я считаю, то, что именно в данном исполнение, `.ToString()` лишний. Вот когда будет идти разработка большого проекта, где каждая доля секунды важна, где важно не удобство, а производительность, тогда да, я с вами согласен, но в большинстве случаев, на это даже не стоит обращать внимание (ИМХО).

Comment: Если убрать ToString(), пишет, что не удаётся явно преобразовать тип "int" в "string".. Я ж пытаюсь в label вставить результат, который он до этого считал в int.

Comment: Извините, не совсем понимаю с тем, что не использовать label4.Text +=. Может, плохо объяснила. Нужно вывести все числа из заданного промежутка, кратные какому-то другому числу. Например (n = 2, m = 7, a = 2) на промежутке от 2 до 7 числа, кратные 2  будут 2, 4 и 6. То есть нужно вывести "2, 4, 6". Есть ли ещё какой-то способ вывести несколько результатов решения через запятую?

Comment: Про названия и int.Parse() поняла. Спасибо! Исправлю.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - полностью с вами согласен.

Comment: `не удаётся явно преобразовать тип "int" в "string"` - я сказал убрать можно только `.ToString()`, а не интерполяцию, то есть `label4.Text += $"{n}, ";`. `не совсем понимаю с тем, что не использовать label4.Text +=` - сейчас вы дергаете постоянно label, когда правильней будет задать ему нужный результат в конце ваших подсчетов. Сделайте в начале `string result = "";`, дальше делайте не `label4.Text +=`, а `result +=`, тем самым у вас будет формироваться одна переменная с результатом, а в конце, просто делайте `label4.Text = result;`, то есть выводите на экран результат.

Comment: Таким образом у вас при каждом клике, `result` будет пустым, и вы по-новому будете его наполнять. А вообще, для таких целей есть `string.Join(",", array)`, который за вас состряпает строку из массива, вам надо лишь сделать массив/коллекцию этих цифр.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ,  string.Join(",", array) изучу, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите очистку лейбла за цикл. Так же можно добавить обработку ошибок.

```csharp
try
{
    int n = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    int m = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    int a = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
    label4.Text = "";
    for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    {
        int x = i % a;
        if (x == 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100); // как я понял, это для красоты здесь
            label4.Text += $"{i.ToString()}, "; 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label4.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Ну или вот более оптимальный вариант

```csharp
try
{
    int n = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    int m = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    int a = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = n; i <= m; i++)
    {
        if (i % a == 0)
            list.Add(i);
    }
    label4.Text = string.Join(", ", list);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label4.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Или вообще вот так

```csharp
try
{
    int n = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    int m = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    int a = int.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
    if (m > n)
        label4.Text = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(n, m - n).Where(i => i % a == 0));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    label4.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: @maps могу написать "быстрый", оптимизированный вариант, если интересно.

Comment: интересно, конечно. )

Comment: @maps обновил ответ

Comment: До такого ещё не дошла. Буду разбираться. Спасибо.